# Wishlist member Registration form url not protected

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wishlist member and created an account. The account (level) has a register url ... my problem is that I was able to go straight to the register url and register without paying... I'm I forgetting something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything any membership website that is using Wordpress had this problem.

The problem is the that registration page need be accessed in order that people will be able to register.

You can however include the login form inside another page make this page not visible so unless someone know the URL he will not be able to find it.

Hope this one have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem.

Wishlist member and the various articles out there will have you believe that when your checkout has "Full" integration you won't be able to access those registration pages unless you are redirected from the checkout process.

This doesn't seem to be the case for me. I have been searching for a solution for a while now but have found nothing.

The main problem is that users are not stupid. Some craft chap will copy and paste that URL the first time and test it to see if he can create a new user for free. Once this is done it's fair game.

Really sucks.